# drawImage() not working - Firebug shows: NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS

Tags: javascript, canvas, drawimage

Why is this little script not working?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<canvas id="can" height="500" width="500"></canvas>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var image = new Image().src="1.jpg";

    context = document.getElementById("can").getContext("2d");

    context.drawImage(image,10,10,480,480);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Firebug in Firefox (latest Version) shows:

```
NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS: Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0 [nsIDOMCanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage]
[Bei diesem Fehler anhalten]    

context.drawImage(image,10,10,480,480);
```

Chrome can't show the image either, they just say `ERROR`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

image.src is async, you need to draw it with a callback.

```
var image = new Image;
image.onload = function() { context.drawImage(image, 10, 10, 400, 400); }
image.src = .....
```

Comment: Thanks its working now but can you explain a little more what happened?

Comment: image data is not loaded when you call image.src = ..., the only way you know it is loaded and available for drawing is to use the onload callback function. what you did was drawing before the image load, thus an error

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is change:

```
   ctx.drawImage(i, 0, 0, arg.width, arg.height);
```

to:

```
   ctx.drawImage(arg.img, 0, 0, arg.width, arg.height);
```